# Setting Splash image to UIWindow programatically in ios Seems compressed horizontally

Tags: ios, splash-screen, uiwindow

If I’m not setting Splash image programatically every thing fine, But I’m setting it because black screen appears if my web service taking long time. So i decided to set an image to window like this.

```
UIImage *splashimg;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 480)
        splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    else  if (screenBounds.size.height == 960)
        splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"];
    else  if (screenBounds.size.height == 1136)
        splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
    else  if (screenBounds.size.height == 1334)
        splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-667h@2x.png"];
    else  if (screenBounds.size.height == 2008)
        splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png"];
     else
         splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default568.png"];

}
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{

    if(UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
            splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png"];

        }
        else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==1536 )
            splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default1024x768@2x.png"];

      else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==1024 )
          splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default768x1024.png"];


        else {
           // splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default768x1024.png"];

      splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];

        }

    }

    else
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
            splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            splashimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape~ipad.png"];


        }


    }

}

 splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 float width = ((UIScreen *)[UIScreen mainScreen]).bounds.size.width;
 float height = (((UIScreen *)[UIScreen mainScreen]).bounds.size.height);
 splashView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, width, height);
 splashView.image=splashimg;
 [self.window addSubview:splashView];
 [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];

[self performSelector:@selector(LoadViewnearby) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
   // here is a web service Which is taking long time, So my window appears white,so instead of white i want to show the image which is same as splash.
```

I want to do exactly like splash. But my image view is getting compressed horizontally when compared to original splash.

Please help me…

Thank you..

Comment: @baydi the Default images are launch Images na

Comment: Try it on device it will not show black screen if you have use launch images properly

Comment: Its showing correct in normal case, I have web service in launching, if that takes long time in low speed n/w getting black screen